# Text is deleted when trying to place the cursor (magnifying glass)

Tags: iphone, ios, bug

I am having a hard time finding documentation on this behavior. The *negative* response received from [this user on everythingiCafe](http://www.everythingicafe.com/forum/threads/things-about-ios-and-apps-that-you-think-could-be-improved.85012/page-14) makes me think that this is a bug. Basically, what happens is:

When you have a string of text that overflows behind the visible input box, or have a string of text which wraps inside the input box, if you move the text cursor around (using the magnifying glass), sometimes the text before the cursor will start to be deleted if you continue to hold the cursor.

It is worth noting that this rate of deleting characters is much faster than holding down the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is it a bug? If not, what are the conditions which trigger this unintuitive method of deleting text?

I am using an iPhone 4 (`MD146LL`) and have experienced this with iOS versions `5.0`, `5.0.1`, and `5.1`.

Comment: Never seen that before.

Comment: I can't make that happen. I have many words inside a text field, I'm moving the cursor around with the magnifying glass and dropping it where I want it. Nothing is being deleted. Am I missing something?

Comment: By the way, that everthingCafe thread looks pretty infantile to me, not sure why you'd want to hang out there to ask questions.

Comment: @Richard I added a minor detail. It happens when I move the cursor, but continue to hold it down. I haven't contributed to everythingiCafe; it is just a related source I found.

Comment: What device and what version of iOS are you using?

Comment: @jtbandes See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I have never observed such behaviour.

**It is a bug.**

Selecting text is not supposed to delete text.